# Can Jenkins used for SSIS ETL automation

Tags: jenkins, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have set of  steps under SQL Agent that loads data from Source to destination and send Email on completion. Can i trigger or automate whole process using Jenkins. 
Is jenkins suitable tool for ETL Automation?

Comment: https://www.eandbsoftware.org/ssis-2012-continuous-integration-using-jenkins-and-octopus-a-journey-to-db-deployment-automation/

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a great tool for ANY automation, in my opinion. I do not work in a typical development shop where we're doing code builds all day / Continuous Integration. I use Jenkins to automate patch installation, SQL code migrations, database clones, you name it. It's even a suitable replacement for cron. I have agents running on all of my nodes, so I can execute whatever I want, wherever I want. If you get into scripted pipelines, you can easily allocate nodes, which allows you to run jobs which have steps on multiple nodes. It's awesome.

Edit: I was using Ansible previously, which is also a great tool, but I like to be able to watch my process output as they execute, some of them are long-runners. Ansible is not so good at letting you do that, by design.